# windows minikube kubectl fail to pull image

Tags: windows, docker, kubectl, minikube

Very simple.  I'm running both docker and minikube on my local machine.
I build a docker image on my windows machine:

```
docker build -t my-service-image:1.0.0
```

Then I create a deployment

```
kubectl create deployment test-node --image=my-service-image:1.0.0
```

Checking event

```
kubectl get events
```

And I see:

```
Error: ErrImagePull
Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

The common suggestion to address this issue on linux/mac is to run the following command before building the docker image

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

However, as stated, this is a windows machine.  What is the easiest way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the question solved?

Answer (score 1):

As I see from this [blog post](https://medium.com/@maumribeiro/running-your-own-docker-images-in-minikube-for-windows-ea7383d931f6), run this command in `powershell` before building your docker image.

```
minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
```

[image]

I couldn't try it out, as I am running ubuntu. Let us know what is the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have very inconvenient but working suggestion for you:

So basically what you can do is:

1) print out all variables to output just using `minikube docker-env` command

2) set **manually** all the variables from previous step using [`set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490998(v=technet.10)) windows command.

Hope this will help.